Why Aws Cognito accepting any password after first time login?
I am implementing AWS with an Android application.
I would like to use Cognito to authenticate our users.
I login with email and password first time properly, If I enter a wrong password, I cannot log in, but after logging in with my password and e-mail the first time, I can log in with any password the next time, so even if the user does not have a password, user only logs in with a correct e-mail. How can I prevent this? After logging out, I delete tokens and other preferences.
Under normal circumstances, when the user wants to log in again, user must login with the correct email and password.
What is wrong with my process?
viewmodel:
@HiltViewModel

    class EnterEmailViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val loginWithEmail: LoginWithEmail,
        private val navigateToRoute: NavigateToRoute,
        private val preferenceManager: IPreferenceManager
    ) : BaseViewModel() {
    
        fun loginWithEmail() {
                val email = _uiState.value.email ?: return
                val password = _uiState.value.password ?: return
        
                launch(onError = {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        when (it) {
                            is NotAuthorizedException,
                            is UserNotFoundException -> _uiEvent.emit(EnterEmailUiEvent.ShowLoginError(R.string.login_error_message))
        
                            else -> showError(it)
                        }
                    }
                }) {
                    loginWithEmail(email, password)
                    preferenceManager.userEmail = email
                    preferenceManager.userPassword = password
                    navigateToRoute(NavigateToMain)
                    _uiEvent.emit(FinishLogin)
                }
            }

LoginWithEmail
class LoginWithEmail @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: IAuthRepository,
    private val preferenceManager: IPreferenceManager,
) {

    suspend operator fun invoke(
        email: String,
        password: String
    ) {
        val response = authRepository.awsCognito(email, password)
        preferenceManager.user = response.toDomainModel()
    }
}

awsCognito
 @Singleton
    class AuthRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val cognitoUserPool: CognitoUserPool,
        private val preferenceManager: IPreferenceManager,
    ) : IAuthRepository {
        override suspend fun awsCognito(email: String, password: String): CognitoUserDetails =
            suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    
                val cognitoUser = cognitoUserPool.getUser(email.trim())
    
                val getDetailHandler = object : GetDetailsHandler {
                    override fun onSuccess(cognitoUserDetails: CognitoUserDetails) {
                        return continuation.resume(cognitoUserDetails)
                    }
    
                    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception?) {
                        continuation.resumeWithException(
                            exception ?: Exception("GetDetailsHandler onFailure")
                        )
                    }
                }
    
                val authHandler = object : AuthenticationHandler {
                    override fun onSuccess(
                        userSession: CognitoUserSession?,
                        newDevice: CognitoDevice?
                    ) {
                        preferenceManager.token = userSession?.idToken?.jwtToken.orEmpty()
                        cognitoUser.getDetailsInBackground(getDetailHandler)
                    }
    
                    override fun getAuthenticationDetails(
                        authenticationContinuation: AuthenticationContinuation?,
                        userId: String?
                    ) {
                        val authDetail = AuthenticationDetails(
                            userId,
                            password.trim(),
                            null
                        )
                        authenticationContinuation?.setAuthenticationDetails(authDetail)
                        authenticationContinuation?.continueTask()
                    }
    
                    override fun getMFACode(continuation: MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation?) {
                        continuation?.continueTask()
                    }
    
                    override fun authenticationChallenge(continuation: ChallengeContinuation?) {
                        continuation?.continueTask()
                    }
    
                    override fun onFailure(exception: Exception?) {
                        continuation.resumeWithException(
                            exception ?: Exception("GetDetailsHandler onFailure")
                        )
                    }
    
                }
    
                cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(authHandler)
            }
    }

